# How to inherit from an Inner Class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an outer class inherited from an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685690/how-to-make-an-outer-class-inherited-from-an-inner-class)

I want to know Can I Inherit some class from Other class inner class?
I want to run below code but I get error.

```
public class Computer {

    int model;

    Computer(int i) {
        model = i;
    }

    public class HardDrive {    
        int size;

        public HardDrive(int i) {
            size = i;
        }

        public HardDrive() {
            size = 40;
        }
    }
}
```

And the main is:

```
class SCSI extends Computer.HardDrive {

    SCSI(Computer c) {
        c.super(80);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> no enclosing instance of type
>   inner.inherit.Computer is in scope

Comment: Please use the search before asking new questions. May questions have already been asked on SO and you may find your answer instantly.

Comment: @brian I searched before asking but I can't find that, I really don't know why I can't find this, tanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me ([See](http://ideone.com/vYtHZ)). Make sure SCSI is in the same namespace as Computer or else use

```
class SCSI extends <namespace>.Computer.HardDrive {
```

Comment: Can you explain more please, I don't get what you mean by namespace :(

Comment: @Am1rr3za sorry in java it's package.

Comment: Yes they are in the same package, I have error on "c.super(80);"

Comment: if look at code from http://ideone.com/vYtHZ that's what I tried and I don't have any compilation errors.

Comment: @Bala RSaw that but still not able to see any explanation for the successfully code. Can you please explain??Why isn't breaking encapsulation??

Comment: you use both SCSI and Computer the inner class of main I didn't want this style

Comment: That's not his question. You're creating a second inner class that inherits from the first which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Brian I did create a second inner class to show it in (http://ideone.com) as I dont know if you can post multiple related files but I did try moving it to a different package and it seemed to be okay (no compilation errors).

Comment: @all I accept the above solution as its working but then how its different from <code> new Computer.HardDrive()</code>

Comment: @Bala - no, you created an inner class in an inner class, then inherited from that in another inner class and passed a reference to the outer class. Also perfectly fine (sort of, there's problems with it). The answer to to OP's original question is "You can't". The answers to the question this is a duplicate of explains why and what you can do (including the problem with your solution).

Comment: @Brian If you look at [this code](http://pastie.org/1812968), here SCSI is not an inner class and the only change that I had to make was to include namespace to the classes and it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

If `SCSI` is not another inner class in `Computer`, you have to make `HardDrive` static.

Comment: make HardDrive Static didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you make HardDrive an inner static class. The reason is that "normal" inner classes have have a relation to an instance of the enclosing class (e.g. you can access the "this" of Computer by writing `Computer.this` in `HardDrive`), so that's why the compiler wants a Computer instance to be in scope. If you make HardDrive static, no such connection between instances of the inner class and the outer class exist, so you can inherit from it without limitation.