# Is Inner Class inherited to subClass of OuterClass?

Tags: java

I tried below code and according to it I have the understanding that inner class is inherited to OuterClass's subclass.Is it correct?

```
    class Outter{
    int i=1;
    class Inner{
        int i=2;
        public void hello(){
            System.out.println("hello from outter.inner");
        }
    }
}

    class ChildClass extends Outter{
        class ChildInner{

        }
    }
    public class Classes {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Inner inner = (new ChildClass()).new Inner();
            System.out.println(inner.i);
            inner.hello();
        }
    }
```

**Output as excepted:**

2

hello from outter.inner

```
Inner inner = (new ChildClass()).new Inner();
```

As this line of code worked it should mean that Inner class is inherited to ChildClass

I am getting confused because of the below statement I found on [Link](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/inheritance-inner-classes-java/)

> When an outer class is extended by it’s sub class, Member inner classes will not be inherited to sub class. To use inner class properties inside the sub class of outer class, sub class must also have an inner class and that inner class must extend inner class of the outer class.

Comment: Ì don't see your point here... `Inner` has a field called `i`, the code is explicitly print the value of that field `inner.i` - this is independent of any parent or outer class. The statement just creates an `Inner` class, that is an inner class of the **new** instance of `ChildClass`, also created in that statement

Comment: Look at first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685690/how-to-make-an-outer-class-inherited-from-an-inner-class

Answer (score 4):

So I will illustrate that statement with an example:

> When an outer class is extended by it’s sub class, Member inner
>   classes will not be inherited to sub class. To use inner class
>   properties inside the sub class of outer class, sub class must also
>   have an inner class and that inner class must extend inner class of
>   the outer class.

```
class Outter {      
    void method(){
       Inner test=new Inner();
       test.i=5; //No problem to do that even if i is private because it is inner class
    } 
    class Inner {
        private int i = 2; 
    }
}

class ChildClass extends Outter{
     void method2(){
        Inner test=new Inner();
        test.i=5;  //Does not compile
        }
}
```

You cannot access "i" in the child class. And if you also extend the inner there you can:

```
class ChildClass extends Outter{
 void method2(){
    Inner2 test=new Inner2();
    test.i=5;  //Compiles fine because we have also extended the inner class (like written in the quoted text)
    }

 class Inner2 extends Inner{     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, So the statement in quote is correct for the private fields. To access private fields from the inner class outside of the Outter class we have to extend Inner class inside subclass of Outer class.

Comment: Just a small correction. You need to make the `i` inside Inner class a `protected`/`public`/`default`. Because as it is `private`, it will give an error in ChildClass

Comment: @Ashish The point explained is if Inner class is inherited in ChildClass but ChildClass is not able to access the private fields of the inner class as it is outside of the Outter class .To make it happen we need to have another class "inner2" which will extend Inner class.

Comment: @Veselin am I correct in the comments I gave above to your answer?

Comment: yes that's right. it needs to be private. if it is public you can access it anyway

Comment: @Veselin can we say now that Inner class is inherited to the subclass of Outter class but private fields are not accessible to the subclass for that to be possible subclass should have another inner class extending Inner class?
**OR** Inner class is not inherited thats why private member are not accessible to the subclass? which one is correct?

Comment: It's kind of two classes. One of them is inner but actually they are still separated. You can extend the outer one or you can extend just the inner one. If you want to keep the inner/outer structure you need to extend both

Comment: So these are like two classes then extending one doesnt mean other will be inherited.
I wonder how this statement is valid :
**Inner inner = (new ChildClass()).new Inner(); **

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
Inner inner = (new ChildClass()).new Inner();
```

Is not really inherited to `ChildClass`

If you break it you are basically doing this:

```
ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
Inner inner = child.new Inner();
```

Now you can call `new Inner()` on the `ChildClass` because it extends `Outter`

This doesn't mean that `ChildClass` can call any of the methods/properties inside `Inner` just because `Inner` is part of `Outter`